# SSTP SERVER without certificate check

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, certificate, sstp, crl

Is it possible to make a SSTP server where clients don't need certificates?  If I want to use linux or microtik routeros as a client, do I have to do something extra in the SSTP server (Windows Server 2008)?

Answer (score 0):

All the references to SSTP, including in the standard itself refer to certificate based authentication for at least the server.